# Replacing blank cells in a range with 0

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to replace all of the empty cells in a range with the number 0. This is my code so far, any help on what I did wrong would be appreciated.

```
        range("A1:O1").Select
        range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        If range("A1:O1").Value = "" Then
        range("A1:O1").Value = 0
        End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a **loop**:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim r As Range, rr As Range

    Set r = Range("A1:O1")
    Set r = Range(r, r.End(xlDown))

    For Each rr In r
        If rr.Value = "" Then rr.Value = 0
    Next rr
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

you can use `SpecialCells()` method of `Range` object:

```
if worksheetfunction.CountBlank(range("A1:O1"))>0 then  range("A1:O1").specialcells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value=0
```

or

```
With Range("A1:O1")
    if worksheetfunction.CountBlank(.Cells) >0 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value=0
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

You problem is that you need all the cells to be blank for the condition to be true. Instead you could define a range and loop over all elements of the range.

```
Sub tmp()
Dim r As Range, cell As Range

Set r = Range(Range("A1:O1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))
For Each cell In r
    If cell.Value = "" Then cell.Value = 0
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: This solution also worked the same as the one above, both were extremely helpful. Thank you!!